# How can I Submit Django Form after Confirmation

Tags: python, django

I am working on a Saving App where I want user to add Customer Deposits after displaying a confirmation form with message. I have tried all I could but I realised that the Deposit function is working fine and displaying the confirmation message but on click confirm on the confirmation form it is not able to submit the deposit form, rather the system redirects me back to deposit form again; displaying an error on the input form that amount Field Can Not be Empty.

Model Code:

```
class Deposit(models.Model):
    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    acct = models.CharField(max_length=6, null=True)
    staff = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    deposit_amount = models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('create_account', args=[self.id])

    def __str__(self):
       return f'{self.customer} Deposited {self.deposit_amount} by {self.staff.username}'
```

Form Code:

```
class CustomerDepositForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
       model = Deposit
       fields = ['deposit_amount']
```

Views Code:

```
def customer_deposit(request, id):
    context = {}
    form = CustomerDepositForm(request.POST or None)
    #Set Page Title
    page_title = "Customer Deposit"
    #Get Current Date
    current_date = datetime.now().date()
    #Get Current Month Name from Calendar
    current_month_name = calendar.month_name[date.today().month]

    try:
        #Check the Customer ID in DB
        customer = Customer.objects.get(id=id)
        #Customer Account
        acct = customer.account_number
   except Customer.DoesNotExist:
        messages.error(request, 'Customer Does Not Exist')
        return redirect('customer_create')
   else:
       #Get the Customer total deposit
       deposit = Deposit.objects.filter(customer_id = id).aggregate(total=Sum('deposit_amount')
       )['total'] or Decimal()
       if request.method == 'POST':
            #Deposit Form
            form = CustomerDepositForm(request.POST or None)
            if form.is_valid():
                amount = form.cleaned_data['deposit_amount']
                context.update(  {
                'deposit':deposit,
                'page_title':page_title,
                'customer':customer,
                'current_date':current_date,
                'current_month_name':current_month_name,
                'form':form,
                'amount':amount,
                'acct':acct,
                })
                return render(request, 'dashboard/deposit_approval_form.html', context)
            
        else:
            form = CustomerDepositForm()
            context = {
            'deposit':deposit,
            'page_title':page_title,
            'customer':customer,
            'current_date':current_date,
            'current_month_name':current_month_name,
            'form':form,
        
            'acct':acct,
            }
            return render(request, 'dashboard/deposit.html', context)

def approve_deposit(request, id):
    user = request.user
    form = CustomerDepositForm(request.POST or None)
    amount = form.cleaned_data['deposit_amount'].value()
    try:
        #Check the Customer ID in DB
        customer = Customer.objects.get(id=id)
        #Customer Account
        acct = customer.account_number
   except Customer.DoesNotExist:
       messages.error(request, 'Customer Does Not Exist')
       return redirect('customer_create')
   else:
       if request.method == 'POST':
           #Create Customer Deposit
           credit_acct = Deposit.objects.create(customer=customer, acct=acct, staff=user,    deposit_amount=amount)
           credit_acct.save()
           messages.success(request, f'N{amount} Credited for Account {acct} Successfully.')
           return redirect('deposit-slip')
               
      else:
          form = CustomerDepositForm()

return render(request, 'dashboard/deposit_approval_form.html')
```

Deposit Approval Template code:

```
<form method="POST">
               {% csrf_token %} 

             

            <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="{% url 'create-deposit' customer.id %}">Cancel</a>

               <input class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" value="Confirm">
           </form>
```

Someone should help with the best way of achieving this. Thanks

Comment: Can you please share the error output because maybe you are not making the necessary migrations?

Comment: No bug in the code rather the form does not submit on confirm submit thereby redirecting user back because the form field (amount) was empty

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `null=True, blank=True`For field which you are not using in form. And then make migrations again

`null = True, blank = False` means that field can be empty in DATABASE but NOT IN FORM and vice versa.

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with the Model but in the logic of approve_deposit function and particularly in the else clause of the try statement. This is because whenever I remove the confirmation form and the object (deposit) directly it works fine without error.

Answer (score 0):

From my Observation, you're not submitting the form in the `try block`, you are only submitting the form in the `else block`. The form will never submit because the `try block` is always true